# Can a Magus use spellstrike with Path of war's maneuvers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, path-of-war

I would really like to know or will maneuvers conflict with the use of spellstrike?

Pathfinder and path of war. My friends and I are planning a pathfinder game. I had intended to play a Magus and one of my friends wanted to play a Warden from Path of war. The gm ok'ed him using it and he started to talk about the maneuvers the three classes of path of war get and that there were feats to allow the original classes from path finder to use them. martial training feats. While lets say a fighter can use them with no problem, just get a few of the matrial training feats and you are good to go. I was thinking into investing some of my feats to use the maneuvers and take advantage of stances.

Comment: Pathfinder and path of war.

Comment: My friends and I are planning a pathfinder game. I had intended to play a Magus and one of my friends wanted to play a Warden from Path of war. The gm ok'ed him using it and he started to talk about the maneuvers the three classes of path of war get and that there were feats to allow the original classes from path finder to use them. martial training feats. While lets say a fighter can use them with no problem, just get a few of the matrial training feats and you are good to go. I was thinking into investing some of my feats to use the maneuvers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boosts and stances yes, strikes and counters no—mostly.

Stances are semi-permanent, passive effects. As long as you are in one, they benefit you the entire time. Boosts are temporary bonuses applied as a swift action, usually only lasting that round. Many of each improve your attacks in some way, and that would include the attacks in spell combat and the attack made during spellstrike.

But strikes require standard actions or full-round actions, so there is a conflict there: spell combat itself requires its own, separate full-round action. You can only use one or the other at a time.

Spellstrike is not a separate action, but it replaces the touch attack made during a spell with a weapon attack: it does not give you another standard action or full-round action with which to use a strike to deliver that spell.

And counters are right out, being immediate actions that occur outside your turn.

The one exception is if you cast a touch-attack spell and hold the charge (either by not taking the free attack, missing the free attack, or by using a spell like *chill touch* that allows multiple touches). In this case, future weapon attacks—including those made as part of strikes or counters—could deliver the touch. This isn’t **usually** all that helpful—after all, you could have already hit with the spell by the time you can deliver it with a strike—but it **is** useful in the case of misses or things like *chill touch*.

But that’s such a niche use that, unless you plan on focusing on a multi-touch spell like that anyway, it’s not a good enough reason to use Martial Training to get strikes. Boosts, counters, and stances will be your way to go.

<sub>Disclaimer: I have done free-lance work for Dreamscarred Press, but I did not work on *Path of War* or *Path of War: Expanded*. My answer is based on my reading of the rules and my memory of conversations with those who did work on it.</sub>